# can we add external bootstrap files to src/main/resources/static folder in intellij community edition

Tags: intellij-idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ihn.png)"I'm currently working on a full-stack project using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. I'm attempting to integrate CSS files downloaded from Bootstrap into my project by placing them in src/main/resources/static. However, I'm facing issues in pasting file into src/main/resources/static.The problem is i am unable to paste files into src/main/resources/static. if i click on the static directory and do paste it not happenig this is my problem, could someone guide me through the process? I've already tried placing the files in the specified directory, but the problem persists.

Comment: *"However, I'm facing issues in pasting file into src/main/resources/static."* - What are these issues?  *"I've already tried placing the files in the specified directory, but the problem persists."* - What problem is that?  It is very difficult to help someone when they don't explain their problems clearly.

Comment: You need to put that information into your question.  Use the EDIT button.

Comment: Try to paste this folder from the OS file manager outside of IntelliJ. Share a couple of screenshots showing the problem to better understand your case. [Disabling](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) third-party plugins and IDE restart may help